# Pig GC overhead limit exceeded when expanding UNION with macros

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera-cdh

I have some data for currency pairs organized like this in HDFS:

> /data/ /data/AUDCAD/
>
> /data/AUDCAD/month1.csv
>
> /data/AUDCAD/month2.csv
>
> ...
>
> /data/EURUSD/month1.csv .. .. ...
>
> ...

(around 60 foloders)

I defined macro

```
DEFINE load_bbo_schema(fname) RETURNS A {
        $A = LOAD '$fname' USING PigStorage(',')
                AS (date:chararray,
                    time:chararray,
                    bidp:float,
                    bidq:int,
                    offp:float,
                    offq:int);
};

DEFINE load_bbo_schema2(name, ccy_pair) RETURNS A {
        T = load_bbo_schema('$name');
        $A = FOREACH T GENERATE *, '$ccy_pair' AS ccypair;
};
```

And then I prepare everything like this:

import 'schemas.pig';

> AUDCAD = load_bbo_schema2('/data/AUDCAD/*','AUDCAD'); AUDCHF =
>   load_bbo_schema2('/data/AUDCHF/*','AUDCHF'); AUDHKD =
>   load_bbo_schema2('/data/AUDHKD/*','AUDHKD'); AUDJPY =
>   load_bbo_schema2('/data/AUDJPY/*','AUDJPY'); ...
>
> ALL_BBO = UNION AUDCAD, AUDCHF, AUDHKD, AUDJPY, AUDNZD, AUDUSD,
>   CADCHF, CADJPY, CHFJPY, CHFNOK, CHFSEK, EURAUD, EURCAD, EURCHF,
>   EURCNH, EURCZK, EURDKK, EURGBP, EURHKD, EURHUF, EURJPY, EURMXN,
>   EURNOK, EURNZD, EURPLN, EURRUB, EURSEK, EURTRY, EURUSD, EURZAR,
>   GBPAUD, GBPCAD, GBPCHF, GBPCZK, GBPHUF, GBPJPY, GBPNOK, GBPNZD,
>   GBPPLN, GBPSEK, GBPUSD, HKDJPY, NOKSEK, NZDJPY, NZDUSD, USDCAD,
>   USDCHF, USDCNH, USDCZK, USDDKK, USDHKD, USDHUF, USDILS, USDJPY,
>   USDMXN, USDNOK, USDPLN, USDRUB, USDSEK, USDSGD, USDTHB, USDTRY,
>   USDUSD, USDZAR, XAGUSD, XAUUSD, ZARJPY;

But when I try to do something with super relation e.g. A = SAMPLE ALL_BBO 000.1; ILLUSTRATE A   i got a lot of garbage in logs like below:

> org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
>   2015-01-14 17:29:17,674 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Processing aliases ALL_BBO,AUDCAD,AUDCHF,AUDHKD,AUDJPY,AUDNZD,AUDUSD,CADCHF,CADJPY,CHFJPY,CHFNOK,CHFSEK,EURAUD,EURCAD,EURCHF,EURCNH,EURCZK,EURDKK,EURGBP,EURHKD,EURHUF,EURJPY,EURMXN,EURNOK,EURNZD,EURPLN,EURRUB,EURSEK,EURTRY,EURUSD,EURZAR,GBPAUD,GBPCAD,GBPCHF,GBPCZK,GBPHUF,GBPJPY,GBPNOK,GBPNZD,GBPPLN,GBPSEK,GBPUSD,HKDJPY,NOKSEK,NZDJPY,NZDUSD,SOME,USDCAD,USDCHF,USDCNH,USDCZK,USDDKK,USDHKD,USDHUF,USDILS,USDJPY,USDMXN,USDNOK,USDPLN,USDRUB,USDSEK,USDSGD,USDTHB,USDTRY,USDUSD,USDZAR,XAGUSD,XAUUSD,ZARJPY,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_0,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_1,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_10,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_11,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_12,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_13,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_14,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_15,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_16,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_17,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_18,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_19,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_2,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_20,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_21,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_22,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_23,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_24,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_25,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_26,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_27,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_28,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_29,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_3,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_30,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_31,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_32,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_33,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_34,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_35,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_36,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_37,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_38,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_39,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_4,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_40,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_41,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_42,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_43,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_44,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_45,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_46,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_47,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_48,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_49,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_5,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_50,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_51,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_52,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_53,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_54,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_55,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_56,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_57,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_58,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_59,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_6,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_60,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_61,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_62,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_63,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_64,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_65,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_66,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_7,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_8,macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_9 2015-01-14 17:29:17,674 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - detailed locations: M: macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_48[2,5],USDCZK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],ALL_BBO[71,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_3[2,5],AUDJPY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_53[2,5],USDJPY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_28[2,5],EURUSD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_62[2,5],USDUSD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_37[2,5],GBPNZD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_15[2,5],EURCZK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_10[2,5],CHFSEK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_44[2,5],NZDUSD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_2[2,5],AUDHKD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_49[2,5],USDDKK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_5[2,5],AUDUSD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_32[2,5],GBPCHF[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_0[2,5],AUDCAD[-1,-1],SOME[2,7],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_63[2,5],USDZAR[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_36[2,5],GBPNOK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_58[2,5],USDSEK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_19[2,5],EURHUF[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_14[2,5],EURCNH[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_56[2,5],USDPLN[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_20[2,5],EURJPY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_29[2,5],EURZAR[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_43[2,5],NZDJPY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_1[2,5],AUDCHF[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_34[2,5],GBPHUF[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_39[2,5],GBPSEK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_65[2,5],XAUUSD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_7[2,5],CADJPY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_52[2,5],USDILS[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_57[2,5],USDRUB[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_24[2,5],EURPLN[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_66[2,5],ZARJPY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_33[2,5],GBPCZK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_38[2,5],GBPPLN[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_6[2,5],CADCHF[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_61[2,5],USDTRY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_11[2,5],EURAUD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_64[2,5],XAGUSD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_12[2,5],EURCAD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_17[2,5],EURGBP[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_51[2,5],USDHUF[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_46[2,5],USDCHF[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_26[2,5],EURSEK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_31[2,5],GBPCAD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_60[2,5],USDTHB[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_16[2,5],EURDKK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_21[2,5],EURMXN[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_42[2,5],NOKSEK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_25[2,5],EURRUB[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_47[2,5],USDCNH[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_30[2,5],GBPAUD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_35[2,5],GBPJPY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_40[2,5],GBPUSD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_45[2,5],USDCAD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_4[2,5],AUDNZD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_9[2,5],CHFNOK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_59[2,5],USDSGD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_54[2,5],USDMXN[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_23[2,5],EURNZD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_18[2,5],EURHKD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_41[2,5],HKDJPY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_8[2,5],CHFJPY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_13[2,5],EURCHF[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_55[2,5],USDNOK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_50[2,5],USDHKD[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_27[2,5],EURTRY[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_22[2,5],EURNOK[-1,-1],null[-1,-1]
>   C:  R:
>   2015-01-14 17:38:11,985 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_55[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_55[-1,-1],USDNOK[13,10],ALL_BBO[71,10],SOME[2,7],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_23[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_23[-1,-1],EURNZD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_62[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_62[-1,-1],USDUSD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_30[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_30[-1,-1],GBPAUD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_10[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_10[-1,-1],CHFSEK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_42[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_42[-1,-1],NOKSEK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_63[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_63[-1,-1],USDZAR[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_31[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_31[-1,-1],GBPCAD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_52[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_52[-1,-1],USDILS[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_20[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_20[-1,-1],EURJPY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_59[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_59[-1,-1],USDSGD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_27[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_27[-1,-1],EURTRY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_39[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_39[-1,-1],GBPSEK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_66[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_66[-1,-1],ZARJPY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_29[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_29[-1,-1],EURZAR[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_4[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_4[-1,-1],AUDNZD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_9[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_9[-1,-1],CHFNOK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_61[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_61[-1,-1],USDTRY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_36[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_36[-1,-1],GBPNOK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_41[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_41[-1,-1],HKDJPY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_48[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_48[-1,-1],USDCZK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_16[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_16[-1,-1],EURDKK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_0[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_0[-1,-1],AUDCAD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_26[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_26[-1,-1],EURSEK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_1[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_1[-1,-1],AUDCHF[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_33[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_33[-1,-1],GBPCZK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_58[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_58[-1,-1],USDSEK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_65[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_65[-1,-1],XAUUSD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_38[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_38[-1,-1],GBPPLN[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_45[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_45[-1,-1],USDCAD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_13[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_13[-1,-1],EURCHF[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_40[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_40[-1,-1],GBPUSD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_8[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_8[-1,-1],CHFJPY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_47[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_47[-1,-1],USDCNH[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_15[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_15[-1,-1],EURCZK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_54[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_54[-1,-1],USDMXN[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_22[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_22[-1,-1],EURNOK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_11[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_11[-1,-1],EURAUD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_6[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_6[-1,-1],CADCHF[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_64[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_64[-1,-1],XAGUSD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_32[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_32[-1,-1],GBPCHF[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_37[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_37[-1,-1],GBPNZD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_7[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_7[-1,-1],CADJPY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_44[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_44[-1,-1],NZDUSD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_12[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_12[-1,-1],EURCAD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_19[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_19[-1,-1],EURHUF[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_51[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_51[-1,-1],USDHUF[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_3[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_3[-1,-1],AUDJPY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_35[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_35[-1,-1],GBPJPY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_53[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_53[-1,-1],USDJPY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_21[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_21[-1,-1],EURMXN[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_60[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_60[-1,-1],USDTHB[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_28[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_28[-1,-1],EURUSD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_5[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_5[-1,-1],AUDUSD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_49[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_49[-1,-1],USDDKK[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_17[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_17[-1,-1],EURGBP[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_24[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_24[-1,-1],EURPLN[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_56[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_56[-1,-1],USDPLN[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_18[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_18[-1,-1],EURHKD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_43[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_43[-1,-1],NZDJPY[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_25[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_25[-1,-1],EURRUB[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_50[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_50[-1,-1],USDHKD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_57[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_57[-1,-1],USDRUB[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_2[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_2[-1,-1],AUDHKD[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_34[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_34[-1,-1],GBPHUF[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_14[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_14[-1,-1],EURCNH[13,10],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_46[2,5],macro_load_bbo_schema2_T_46[-1,-1],USDCHF[13,10] C:  R: 
>   2015-01-14 17:38:13,550 [Service Thread] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - Spilled an estimate of 5511408 bytes from 1 objects. init = 526909440(514560K) used = 699182936(682795K) committed = 699400192(683008K) max = 699400192(683008K)
>   2015-01-14 17:39:21,345 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. GC overhead limit exceeded

Am I doing it wrong, or Pig just can't handle it?

I am using Pig v12 against hadoop 2.3.0, both from Cloudera distribution (CDH5). Tried using newest Pig but without luck

Comment: Give that Pig some mud, maybe it'll like it :) (Couldn't resist)

Comment: I feel like im crawling in mud myself here ._.

Comment: Did you try giving it some more memory?

Comment: I tried with pig -Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx3088m, still turns into dead pork :|

Comment: Personally I do not trust ILLUSTRATE. Had quite often the case that ILLUSTRATE crashed with some weird error, but running the thing for real worked fine.

Comment: @LiMuBei you might have a point, i did some tweaks and ILLUSTRATE still explodes, but other stuff started to work